# Audit Backlog hangs linux server?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system

I am using centos 7 server in which am running realtime Multithreaded processes. After 2 or 3 days of continues running server goes to freeze state and am not able to access it.One time i luckily logged in and i saw CPU

```
[564378.509785] audit_log_start: 14 callbacks suppressed    
[564678.515440] audit: audit_backlog=65 > audit_backlog_limit=64    
[564678.522037] audit: audit_lost=22 audit_rate_limit=0 audit_backlog_limit=64    
[564678.529822] audit: backlog limit exceeded
```

Is it possible like some thread/process is hanged and due that auditd is not able to log the events?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the filesystem got stuck in the frozen state. The underlying problem may have different roots.

You can try to find the issue by examining additional logs, for instance you can use

```
aureport --start today(any date you are interested in)
```

Additionally try to tune your configuration

```
-b
sets the maximum amount of existing Audit buffers in the kernel, for example:
```

You may need to increase this configuration option by editing the `/etc/audit/audit.rules` file, for example changing it to `-b 8192`.

Also it may help to increase priority in the `/etc/audit/auditd.conf` file by modifying the `priority_boost` option.

Comment: Which filesystem got stuck like "proc" or "sys" etc. Any idea?